# Как сменить подсеть, получаемую по умолчанию компьютером?

Tags: ip, сеть

Ситуация такая. При загрузке одной из машин в подсети она автоматом динамически получает айпишник из подсети 192.168.100.x, тогда как остальные компы, соединенные с этим же концентратором, получают ip из диапозона 192.168.10.x. 
Проблема в том, что эти две подсети вообще не видят друг друга, не пингуются и т.д.
Магия в том, что при физическом переподключении сетевого кабеля выше обозначенный комп без проблем автоматом получает так же, как и все, айпишник из 192.168.10.x и после естественно прекрасно видит всех своих собратьев по локалке. 
Вопрос в том, как мне сделать, чтобы этот гад автоматом получал адрес из нужного диапозона без тупых шаманств с переподключением сетевого кабеля?

Answer (score 2):

Магии тут никакой нет. Есть просто активное устройство, которое раздает адреса из подсети 192.168.100.0

Концентратор (hub, switch) не имеет к делу никакого отношения, так как работает на канальном (2-ом) уровне модели OSI. Иными словами, он пропускает все IP-пакеты которые через него проходят.

Для того, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, хорошо бы представлять топологию сети, коммутацию и наличие активных устройств и/или DHCP-серверов, которые могут потенциально *раздать* адреса из "не той" подсети. Как только дополните вопрос, я дополню ответ.

Активное устройство теоретически может "висеть" на другом интерфейсе (сетевой карте) того же компьютера или даже на каком-нибудь айфоне с включенным режимом общего доступа, воткнутом в USB. Вариант "забыл отключить статическое назначение IP" я не рассматриваю.

Comment: Interface Unknown, поправьте адрес подсети. 110й в вопросе не было.

Comment: Судя по тому, что после переподключения ip все же назначается, статического IP быть не должно

Comment: @PavelMayorov ага, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ участника Interface Unknown методикой поиска виновника. Когда комп получает адрес из "левой" подсети - обязательно посмотрите адрес DHCP-сервера в настройках соединения. Скорее всего, это будет 192.168.100.1

Теперь на любом компьютере, который имеет адрес из этой подсети (либо на проблемном, либо на своем - во втором случае такой адрес надо ему самостоятельно добавить) запускаем вечный пинг этого адреса: `ping -t 192.168.100.1`. Теперь надо по-очереди отключать от сети все устройства, следя за пингом. Как прервался - значит, виновник на той стороне провода (ну, или мы отключили тот компьютер, на котором и был запущен пинг).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь. Да, действительно было два DHCP-сервера в сети, на двух роутерах. В итоге на 192.168.100.1 отключил этот сервис - и все раздает, как надо.